# Address of allocated memory not the same when running under valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I am testing `valgrind` and have this small C program that leaks 4 bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf( "Address: %p\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with: `gcc -g -o leak leak.c`, and run it:

```
$ leak
Address: 0x55a72e303260
$ leak
Address: 0x55f370273260
```

So it shows two different addresses for two separate runs. However if I run it under valgrind it always shows the same address: `0x4a66040`:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all  leak
==8186== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8186== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8186== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8186== Command: leak
==8186== 
Address: 0x4a66040
==8186== 
==8186== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8186==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==8186==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,028 bytes allocated
==8186== 
==8186== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==8186==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8186==    by 0x109156: main (leak.c:6)
==8186== 
==8186== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8186==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==8186==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8186==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8186==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8186==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8186== 
==8186== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8186== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Why is this so? And is it possible for `valgrind` to show the real address of the memory?

Comment: But that is the "real" address (Always a fuzzy thing when talking about virtual memory) when running under valgrind and the allocator it uses.

Comment: [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) ensures that the address where the program runs is normally not consistent. Valgrind is a debugging tool so that would be unhelpful. The addresses are virtual, an application progam has no access to real addresses.

Comment: @WeatherVane Does that mean that it not possible to free the memory later? For example, my test program printed address:  `0x55a72e303260`, then I could not later create a program that did `void *addr = (void*)0x55a72e303260; free(addr)` ?

Comment: You can only `free` the memory at an address that was allocated by `malloc` function family. Or in other words, you can only pass an address to `free` that was returned by `malloc` etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I did allocate it by `malloc`, right? So can it then be `free`d later is the question

Comment: In that case why should it not be possible to `free` the memory later? Unless you corrupted memory, or altered the value of the pointer you were returned.  I don't see the point of hard-coding a pointer value: because it won't be the same from one run to the next.

Comment: So it is not possible to free leaked memory later even if you know the address of the leaked memory?

Comment: You should keep track of the addresses that are returned by `malloc()` and friends so that you can pass them to `free()` later. Not doing so is asking for trouble.

Comment: Ok, I think you misunderstood the question. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Right, your main question was probably answered by the first comment by @WeatherVane. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: @marcolz So then the answer is: it is not possible to free the memory later, even if you know the address because of the randomization feature.

Comment: A "leak" means you haven't `free`d memory. There's no reason why you can't `free` memory, but copying the address given by Valgrind isn't the way to do it (and won't be repeatable in the proper version): you should find out *why* there is a leak, instead of trying to use sticking plaster.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok, thanks I agree on finding the cause of the leak, but my question was about freeing leaked memory from another process. I guess this leaves me still confused, and I will rather ask a new question than continuing this discussion in the comments..

Comment: Well, you are correct in that you *can* `free()` any address that was previously allocated by `malloc()` and friends.

Comment: @marcolz Added [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57571539/2173773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* the "real" address of the allocated memory.

Valgrind replaces your `malloc()` implementation with its own version, so that it can do what it does, see the line:

```
==8186==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

So it is the underlying call to obtain memory that differs between your "normal" libc implementation of `malloc()` and that of valgrind's implementation. Likely libc uses `brk()` and valgrind uses `mmap()`.

`brk()` follows the rules of [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) while `mmap()` allows for explicitly selecting the virtual memory address where to map the newly allocated memory.

Edit: `strace` of both versions, shows:

libc:

```
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5611e25ec000
brk(0x5611e260d000)                     = 0x5611e260d000
fstat(1, {st_dev=makedev(0, 22), st_ino=67, st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=5, st_blksize=1024, st_blocks=0, st_rdev=makedev(136, 64), st_atime=1566292432 /* 2019-08-20T11:13:52.993864629+0200 */, st_atime_nsec=993864629, st_mtime=1566292432 /* 2019-08-20T11:13:52.993864629+0200 */, st_mtime_nsec=993864629, st_ctime=1564479628 /* 2019-07-30T11:40:28.009864433+0200 */, st_ctime_nsec=9864433}) = 0
write(1, "Address: 0x5611e25ec260\n", 24) = 24
```

valgrind:

```
mmap(0x4c2c000, 2158912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x4c2c000
...
write(1027, "==18842==    at 0x4C2FB0F: mallo"..., 91) = 91
```

So in fact Valgrind explicitly chooses where to map its memory pool.

Comment: If I run the program under `valgrind` repeatedly it always prints: `Address: 0x4a66040` why is it always the same?

Comment: Because the valgrind implementation of `malloc()` is not affected by - or possibly explicitly avoids - address space randomization.

Comment: So the reported address `0x4a66040` is not the real address of the allocated memory, but some address in valgrinds buffers. That's why valgrind can free `0x4a66040` for each run, and be able to reallocate the same buffer at the exactly the same place at the next run?

Comment: Yes, I just edited my answer with `strace` output, showing that valgrind explicitly selects where its buffer is allocated in the virtual address space of your process.